# flask_sqlalchemy: error with `__setattr__` to `DefaultMeta`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

After re-building a Docker image, I've started to get the following error:

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.8-slim /bin/bash
...
$ pip install flask_sqlalchemy
...
$ python -c "from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy; SQLAlchemy()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 715, in __init__
    self.Model = self.make_declarative_base(model_class, metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 797, in make_declarative_base
    model.query_class = self.Query
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/api.py", line 79, in __setattr__
    _add_attribute(cls, key, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py", line 802, in _add_attribute
    type.__setattr__(cls, key, value)
TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to DefaultMeta object
```

The versions of the specific packages involved:

```
python -c "import sqlalchemy, flask_sqlalchemy; print(sqlalchemy.__version__, flask_sqlalchemy.__version__)"
1.3.18 # sqlalchemy
2.4.3 # flask_sqlalchemy
```

Although I've also experienced the error with versions `1.3.17` and `2.4.1`.

Answer (score 12):

After some experimentation, it seems like the issue is due to some change between `python:3.8.3-slim` and `python:3.8.4-slim`.

To reproduce, notice that this works:

```
$ docker run --rm -it python:3.8.3-slim …
```

Where this does not:

```
docker run --rm -it python:3.8.4-slim …
```

It looks like this bug/fix is the cause of the issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue39960

Comment: Can confirm that it's a Python 3.8.4 specific issue. Had to change my Dockerfile (for use with Buildkite) to say `FROM python:3.8.3` instead of `FROM python:3.8` (and added a TODO comment to change it back once https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/21473 is resolved and is in a stable python > 3.8.4).

Comment: Same here. Changed Dockerfile for now.

Comment: I have learned my lesson not completely pinning dependencies. Thanks for the quick fix/post, helped a lot.

Comment: Same here, had to fix the minor version in Dockerfile to 3.8.3